# Thousand separator in C++

Tags: c++

I want to create a string in C++ with the following format:

```
string + numbersWithFormatAndThousandSeparator + string
```

I am not sure whether `std::string` or `snprintf()` provides format like that especially the thousand separator. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 8):

Fast and easy way:

```
std::ostringstream ss;
ss.imbue(std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"));
ss << 1033224.23;
return ss.str();
```

Would return a string "1,033,244.23"

But it requires `en_US.UTF-8` locale to be configured on your system.

Comment: THat worked for me on one machine, but failed on another ("locale not found" or something. Then I tried simply `ss.imbue(std::locale(""));` . This worked. I think that "" selects the default locale for your system, and hopefully that'll be what you, and your users, want. Note that `locale()` failed (no thousands separator).

Answer (score 3):

C++ locale: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/

Answer (score 0):

Information (including the separator for thousands) for formatting numeric values is available in the `<clocale>` header. That header provides a `lconv` struct which has the information you need. In particular, the struct features a `char *thousands_sep` member which might be just what you need.

See the [struct lconv](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/clocale/lconv/) documentation for all the details.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to properly format a number in C++. Check out this article for some of them (`boost::lexical_cast` is my personal favorite): http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/numb_to_text/

Comment: Unless I'm missing how, lexical_cast doesn't do thousands separators?

Comment: AFAIK lexical_cast uses the current global locale. So if thousand separators are present in the locale, they will be parsed/formatted properly.