# C++ Dot separation of large numbers with cout

Tags: c++, numbers, int, cout, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Thousand separator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163243/thousand-separator-in-c)

i have some large Number as "unsigned long long" like:

```
1431498243532
1544355634442
845545342344
5284493424
```

and I want them printed by cout in the following way:

```
1.431.498.243.532
1.544.355.634.442
  845.545.342.344
    5.284.493.424
```

I figured out how to get the alignment right, but can't find a way to get the Dots in there.
Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It is interesting though, that the possible duplicate doesn't contain particularly good answers (beyond RTFM). It is also unclear whether this is about using the default locale (since this is not an English thousands separator).