# print 1000er separated values

Tags: c

My function doesn't work as expected. The goal is the print into a buffer a human readable string of physical units on an embedded device (with LCD). E.g. `1234uV` shall be displayed as `+1.234mV` where `-100023uV` as `-1.000,230 V`. How is the correct (fast and safe) implementation with optionally right adjustment (at `uV`)?

```
uint8 voltage_string(char* buf, int32 uVolt)
{
    static const int32 VOLT = 1000000;
    static const int32 MILLIVOLT = 1000;

    const int32  V =  uVolt / VOLT;
    const int32 mV = (uVolt - V*VOLT) / MILLIVOLT;
    const int32 uV = (uVolt - V*VOLT - mV*MILLIVOLT);

    uint8 n = 0;

    if(abs(V) > 0) {
        n  = sprintf(buf,     "%+d",    V);
        n += sprintf(buf + n, ",%3d",   abs(mV));
        n += sprintf(buf + n, ".%3d V", abs(uV));

        return n;
    }

    if(abs(mV) > 0) {
        n  = sprintf(buf,     "%+d",     mV);
        n += sprintf(buf + n, ",%3d mV", abs(mV));

        return n;
    }

    if(abs(uV) > 0) {
        n  = sprintf(buf,     "%+3d uV", uV);

        return n;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: Set the locale to German and use the `'` modifier for the format specifier in `printf`...

Comment: Did you tag this as C++ because you were expecting C++ answers? If not, you should remove that tag; the example code seems to be entirely C to me.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163243/) contains several pointers on how to print numbers with thousand separators in C++. There is not need to implement this functionality yourself.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++ ? It looks like straight C code to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
uint8_t voltage_string(char* buf, int32_t uVolt) 
{     
    const int32_t VOLT = 1000000;     
    const int32_t MILLIVOLT = 1000;      
    int v=0,mv=0,uv=0;
    uint8_t n = 0;      
    v = uVolt/VOLT;
    mv = (uVolt % VOLT) / MILLIVOLT;
    uv = (uVolt % VOLT) % MILLIVOLT;
    n = sprintf(buf, "%d.%03d%03d  V", v,mv,uv); 
    return n; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is way more complicated than it needs to be - you could simplify it to something like this:

```
uint8_t voltage_string(char* buf, int32_t uVolt)
{
    const int32_t VOLT = 1000000;
    const int32_t MILLIVOLT = 1000;

    uint8_t n = 0;

    if (abs(uVolt) >= VOLT)
    {
        n = sprintf(buf, "%+.6f V", uVolt / (double)VOLT);
    }
    else if (abs(uVolt) >= MILLIVOLT)
    {
        n = sprintf(buf, "%+.3f mV", uVolt / (double)MILLIVOLT);
    }
    else
    {
        n = sprintf(buf, "%+d µV", uVolt);
    }

    return n;
}
```